# Can't connect to the INTERNET on a new and fresh install of Ubuntu Server 23.10

Tags: ethernet, ubuntu, connection, internet, server

After a week of trial and error, Ubuntu Server 23.10 is FINALLY running on my Pi. **FRESH install!**

The device is a Pi Zero 2 W, and the OS is currently running in loopback mode. It is unable to get internet, despite being connected directly to the tap (ISP) via Ethernet Cable.

This is the full `ip addr show` message:

```
1: 10: <LOOPEACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default glen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.041/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferrednIft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferredelft forever
2: wlanO: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICASTAM> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f9:d9:dd:ff:d9:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    (Intentionally obfuscated the link/ether mac address)
```

**How can I get around this hurdle, fix the Pi's no-internet issue, and connect via ssh from my computer?**

Comment: Ok, I fixed the wifi connectivity issues by following the recommendations in https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server , with `sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and some proper local wifi settings and then `sudo netplan apply` and `sudo reboot` **BUT I still have to fix my ethernet issue. Therefore the question is still valid and up-to-date**